# How to retrive name property of previous attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

hi i am newbie in jquery..

i have code like follow

```
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <a href="#" onclick="dele(this)">Remove</a>
```

my question is how can i pass **name property** of textbox in function **dele()**?

i am trying to do is

```
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <a href="#" onclick="dele(this.prev().attr('name'))">Remove</a>
```

but it's giving me error. i don't how can i retrieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prev is a method that comes with jQuery. `this` is an instance of JS Native DOM element. use $(this) to make a jQuery Instance.

```
dele($(this).prev().attr('name'))
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <a href="#" class="link">Remove</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.link').click(function(){
        var name = $(this).prev().attr('name');
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your ans it worked but i wanted it in inline... +1